# Create a Dynamic Entity Framework Where Query

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

At runtime I have a dynamic list of "Parent" ids i need to query against one of my entity tables, using LINQ how would I generate the query at run time? Currently am (VERY SLOWLY) looping over my list of ID's and performing a separate query to the database using the Where method. Is there an API that will allow me to build a single WHERE statement that in essence is appending "&& value = something" as I would have if I was writing the SQL myself?

Currently what i do looks like this

```
            foreach(var parent in parents)
        {
            col.AddRange(context.LocalAuthorities.Where(c => c.Parent.ID == parent.ID).ToList());
        }
```

Comment: Please, add more details. What is your current query?

Comment: will add an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to replace *multiple* iterative queries by *one* query, you can use this approach:

```
var allParentIds = parents.Select(p=>p.ID).ToList();
var result = context.LocalAuthorities.Where(c=> allParentIds.Contains(c.Parent.ID));

col.AddRange(result);
```

Comment: I didn't think entity framework could translate a contains method call. I know this works with linq to objects, I will try this and get back to you. :)

Comment: Perfect and simple, i guess i should have checked before assuming it would not works. Much appreciated!